# как добавить в vscode подсказки по ajax методов и свойств?

Tags: visual-studio-code

как добавить в vscode подсказки по json?
Может какое нибудь расширение есть? а то что не пишу ничего не знает(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

[IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) вот по поиску найдет для разных языков, да возможно вы просто не включили подсказки напротив функции `i`

Comment: ок, попробую спасибо